# Access fields of child classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, mongoid

EDIT : sorry I forgot to mention I was using Mongoid, those `field` were Mongoid ones

I have a rails application that is responsible for generating Word documents (and replacing some variables inside)

So I have many `DocumentEtude::xxxx` classes that superclass a base `DocumentEtude` class (in english `ProjectDocument`)

```
class DocumentEtude
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :shared_field
class DocumentEtude:xxxx < DocumentEtude
  field :only_in_xxxx_field
```

In order to keep my sanity, I'd like to have all the variables in one single place, and do something like this

```
class DocumentEtude
    ...
    def variables
            vars = {}
            case _type
            when 'DocumentEtude::xxxxx', 'DocumentEtude::yyyyyy', 'DocumentEtude::zzzzzz'
                vars.merge!({
                    "some_var" => shared_field,
                    "some_var2" => only_in_xxxx_field
                    ...
    end

    def generate_document
      # Code that uses the variables defined before
    end
```

Now the problem is that I declare this method inside DocumentEtude, however 
I need to access some fields that are only declared in child classes (`only_in_xxxx_field` for example), yet apparently Ruby isn't able to find them. Any idea how I could do this ?

Comment: can you give an example of how you want to access them?

Comment: I reedited my question. For example I may have a `DocumentEtude::Bill` where I have extra fields `price`, `tax`, etc. And I would like to put these variables inside a Hash (which is then used to replace content in the xml of my word documents)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `fields` class method or `attributes` instance method? Can't you start with those and filter out the usual suspects?

Comment: *bang* *bang* ...is the sound of my head against the wall for making such a stupid mistake.

I realised that I was doing only one `case when` and putting the same document type in multiple `when`. So obviously, only the first one would be executed, only merging a fraction of the actual variables and giving me the impression something wasn't working properly...

Comment: See my last comment... It's really about a stupid mistake that doesn't make it a real question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to have some kind *settings* which is inherited down the class hierarchy. If that is the case use the ActiveSupport's core extension [`class_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute). For example (copied from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#class-attributes):

```ruby
class A
  class_attribute :x
end

class B < A; end

class C < B; end

A.x = :a
B.x # => :a
C.x # => :a

B.x = :b
A.x # => :a
C.x # => :b

C.x = :c
A.x # => :a
B.x # => :b
```

The only thing that you must be aware of are `mutables` (like the hash that your are using). But since in your case it is even desired for the subclass to overwrite the values of super class, you are good to go.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't talking about class_attributes but instance ones. However I didn't know about this ActiveSupport and it will be useful for me in other places.

Comment: Your case statement uses the class type and your field statement binds the value to the class. And moreover, class_attribute provides you instance level setters and getters.

Comment: Ah yes *instance level setters and getters*. Sorry I first missed this line when reading your link : *They can also be accessed and overridden at the instance level*.

Answer (score 0):

you can always define a method that returns the field you defined in your child class and call it in your parent class method.

Example

```
class DocumentEtude
    def variables
            vars = {}
            vars.merge!(
              "some_var" => shared_field,
              "some_var2" => your_customized_field)
            ...
    end
end

class DocumentEtude::XXXX < DocumentEtude
  field :only_in_xxxx_field

  def your_customized_field
    return only_in_xxxx_field
  end
end
```

Of course, it is a good idea to let the user know if some fields the parent class is trying to access are not defined in a child class, by adding this in your parent class:

```
def your_customized_field
  raise NotImplementedError, "This field is not defined yet!"
end
```

Hope this help.